# AngularJS - How to control Authorization header?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, http-headers, authorization

I have a problem controlling the Authorization header submitted towards the server by my AngularJS application. Sometimes it goes into this loop where no matter what username/password I fill in, an older and valid version of the Authorization header is submitted - which means that the user might get authorized even when the credentials he provided was not valid!

This is how I set the Authorization header on my request:

```
$http({
      method: "PUT",
      url: "/api/v1/auth/authorize",
      headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + btoa($scope.credentials.username + ":" + $scope.credentials.password)
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + token;
```

Comment: But I don't want Authorization set on every request - only the log in request.